# How to detect a point is above on the plane or below in $\mathbb{R}^3$ given a plane equation and a point?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a plane with equation of $x+2y+z=1$ and I have a point (-38,-46,129) and I want to know that on which side of the plane does this point is present(Above or Below the plane)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is not about how to use Mathematica.

Comment: Is (0,0,0) above or below?

Comment: @Moti it is below the plane.

Comment: See the answer by Lakshy. Accept it for his benefit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that by "below", you mean the point is on the same side as the origin, w.r.t. the given plane, and by "above", you mean that the point is on the opposite side of the w.r.t. the given plane.

Under the given assumption,You could simply substitute the point coordinates in the plane expression(ax+by+cz=d changes to ax+by+cz-d) and also substitute the point (0,0,0) in the given expression, and compare the signs of the value you get.
If the value for the point is zero, it means that the point lies on the given plane.
If the value for the point has the same sign as the origin, then it lies on the same side of the plane as the origin.
If the value for the point has opposite sign as that of the origin, then, the point and the origin lie on opposite sides of the plane.